# Ufw denying and re-allowing without adding two rules

Tags: ufw

So I'm using Fail2ban and the way it bans and unbans IP addresses is by using the `ufw deny from xx.xx.xx.xx to any` and `allow`. However, because new rules need to stay on the top of the list (above the allow any any), I can't seem to *reallow* access without manually doing a `ufw status numbered` and deleting the original rule.

Is there any way that I can do something like `ufw allow from x.x.x.x to any` and automatically *remove* any existing "deny" rules? Otherwise, I'm not sure how fail2ban can ever *remove* an IP ban with ufw once it has already been placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delete a rule from `ufw` by specifying it the same way you did when adding it, but specifying to `delete` it instead.

For instance, if you blocked an IP address with:

```
ufw deny from 203.0.113.85 to any
```

You would remove the rule with:

```
ufw delete deny from 203.0.113.85 to any
```

If you read the file `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/ufw.conf` you will see that this is exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the "delete" argument in this to remove the blacklist. Without the "delete" argument provided, it just adds another entry, which doesn't really remove the blacklist.